# Scrapy Spider Parser call function

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

How can I call the writeXML after my parser finish crawling data? Currently I can see the data crawl but don't see the output file. I tried to print under writeXML no output too.

Below are my code:

```
class FriendSpider(BaseSpider):
    # identifies of the Spider
    name = "friend"
    count = 0 
    allowed_domains = ["example.com.us"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://example.com.us/biz/friendlist/"
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(0,1722,40):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://example.com.us/biz/friendlist/?start=%d" % i)

    def parse(self, response):
        response = response.replace(body=response.body.replace('<br />', '\n')) 
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Item()
            self.count += 1
            item['id'] = str(self.count)
            item['name'] = site.select('.//div/div/h4/text()').extract()
            item['address'] = site.select('h4/span/text()').extract()
            item['review'] = ''.join(site.select('.//div[@class="review"]/p/text()').extract())
            item['birthdate'] = site.select('.//div/div/h5/text()').extract()

            items.append(item)
        return items

    def writeXML(self, items):
        root = ET.Element("Test")
        for item in items:
            item= ET.SubElement(root,'item')
            item.set('id', item['id'])
            address= ET.SubElement(item, 'address')
            address.text = item['address']
            user = ET.SubElement(item, 'user')
            user.text = item['user']
            birthdate= ET.SubElement(item, 'birthdate')
            birthdate.text = item['birthdate']
            review = ET.SubElement(item, 'review')
            review.text = item['review']

        # wrap it in an ElementTree instance, and save as XML
        file = open("out.xml", 'w')
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
        tree.write(file,xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8',method="xml")
```

Answer (score 2):

To output using the built-in XML exporter, try the following command:

```
scrapy crawl friend -o items.xml -t xml
```

If the output isn't to your liking, then you can try creating your own exporter using the [XMLExporter class](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html?highlight=output#xmlitemexporter) as a basis.

Comment: I tried use XMLExporter item_element="id" -> it give me <id> but I want <item id='1'>